# Unexpected token in JSON at position 39

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, json

I have a php api for a dictionary web app,

```
$outp = "";

while($rs = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    if ($outp != "") {$outp .= ",";}
    $outp .= '{"WORD":"'  . $rs["word"] . '",';
    $outp .= '"MEANING":"'   . $rs["definition"]        . '"}';
}
$outp ='{"records":['.$outp.']}';
$conn->close();

echo($outp);

}
else
{


}
?>
```

and at the angularJS side the parsing function is as follows :

```
$scope.counter = function() {
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(response));

    if($scope.name) {
        $http.get("http://localhost/dictionary/API/search.php?qr="+$scope.name)
            .then(function (response) {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(response.records));
            if(response.data.records=="") {
                queryRes = response.data.records ;
                $scope.word = "";
                $scope.meaning = ""
            } else {

                queryRes = response.data.records ;
                $scope.word = queryRes[0].WORD;
                $scope.meaning = queryRes[0].MEANING;
            }

    });

    }

}
```

there is no error when the php api returns single element array JSON like this

```
{"records":[{"WORD":"Net","MEANING":"വല"}]}
```

But when php returns array of multiple elements like ,

```
{"records":[{"WORD": "End","MEANING": "അറുതി
"},{"WORD": "End","MEANING": "അവസാനം
"},{"WORD": "End","MEANING": "അതിര്‌
"},{"WORD": "End","MEANING": "സീമ
"},{"WORD": "End","MEANING": "പരിസമാപ്‌തി
"},{"WORD": "End","MEANING": "അവസാനഘട്ടം
"},{"WORD": "End","MEANING": "മരണം
"}]}
```

Getting error like this

```
Unexpected token in JSON at position 39 at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
```

I think JSON object manipulation is having some problem.

Comment: you can print_out the string you received in js, and paste it here http://json.parser.online.fr/ to check where is the problem.

Comment: I have checked it and found there is some problem with JSON manipulation in the php side. Now solved by using ryan's answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don’t build JSON by string concatenation; use [`json_encode`](https://php.net/json_encode).

```
$records = [];

while($rs = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $records[] = [
        'WORD' => $rs["word"],
        'MEANING' => $rs["definition"],
    ];
}
$conn->close();

echo json_encode(['records' => $records]);
```

Comment: Thank you! It was the problem!